# Irregular Polygon: Coordinates missing

Tags: java, algorithm, graphics, drawing, polygon

I need to draw an irregular polygon with coordinates showing. My problem is that my polygon is being displayed but the coordinates are not being shown. I want it to be like, with each mouse click, the coordinates are being shown. Part of my code:

```
public void RegPoly() {
          // Draw the polygon described by the arrays xCoord and yCoord
          // and the integer pointCt.  A filled polygon with a black 
          // outline is drawn.  If pointCt is 0 or 1, nothing is drawn.
          // If pointCt is 2, only a black line is drawn.
       //More than 2, polygon!

       if (pointCt < 2) //pointCt = no of inputs
          return;
       Graphics g = getGraphics();
       if (pointCt == 2) {
          g.drawLine(xCoord[0], yCoord[0], xCoord[1], yCoord[1]);
       }
       else {
          //g.setColor(Color.red); //filling colors
          //g.fillPolygon(xCoord, yCoord, pointCt);
          g.setColor(Color.black);
          g.drawPolygon(xCoord, yCoord, pointCt);
          g.drawString("("+xCoord+","+yCoord+")", xCoord[500], yCoord[500]);
       }
       g.dispose();
   }


   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { 
         // Process a user mouse-click.

  if ( pointCt > 0 && (Math.abs(xCoord[0] - e.getX()) <= 2)
                          && (Math.abs(yCoord[0] - e.getY()) <= 2) ) {

         RegPoly();
         pointCt = 0;
      }
      else if ( pointCt == 500) {

         RegPoly();
         pointCt = 0;
      }
      else {

         xCoord[pointCt] = e.getX();
         yCoord[pointCt] = e.getY();
         pointCt++;
         if (pointCt >= 2) {
            putLine(xCoord[pointCt-2], yCoord[pointCt-2], 
                         xCoord[pointCt-1], yCoord[pointCt-1]); 


         }
```

Comment: be more specific: what language,platform,gfx api... What do you mean by coordinates shown (where how as what ... like text near vertex/status bar ...as point disc... ). Do not recognize the gfx api but the draw string looks suspicious I expect parameters like single 2D position not array of 500 points ... if you want to tag all clicked points then use for loop

Comment: @Spektre language: Java ... Graphics! Like when a mouse click event occurs, it shows the coordinates